# F1 Manager - How to choose the strategy before and during the race?

Tags: f1-manager

I recently started playing F1 Manager on Android. It seems to be a similar and simplified version of Motorsport Manager.

Every time I play this kind of games I struggle trying to find the best choice for the strategy, so I want to ask you something about that:

1. When should we choose hard tyres instead of soft ones? Do they have a different wear level based on track and air condition (e.g. when cloudy use soft, when sunny use hard)?
2. Usually in motorsport management games car performance gets worse when you reach 25% or 20% of tyre wear, while here on F1 Manager it seems like you are ok until you are over 0%. When you reach 0% the car is slower. Am I right?
3. Is it in general better making 2 stops using soft tyres instead of making 1 stop with hard tyres?
4. What is the threshold for the wet tyres? I'm quire sure that over 50% you have to go for them, but not sure when soft tyres starts being better.

Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

For tracks that are 6 or less laps or if the second weather condition is rain, use hard tires. For tracks that are 7+ laps and there is no rain for the second weather condition, use soft tires. You are correct that tires are OK if above 0% (unless you are almost done with the race). For sunny short tracks, it is better to use soft tires and 2 stop strategy. Depends on weather. The threshold for wet tires is +50% water but if under 50%, use soft tires if short track and hard tires for long track. Pro tip: use the green speed button at the beginning of the race and use red button after half way through race or after 1st pit stop, depending on which scenario comes first. Hope this helps!